# changing control source in access report textbox

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have an access report where I wanted to make a textbox control source dynamic based on the current date using this to limit data returned to the last 5 years based on the current date.
I'm bring back the number of claims for the past 5 years based on the accident year.

Working:  =Sum(IIf([accidYr]>(Year()-6),[numClaims],0))

It works just fine but............
When I click off or save and reopen the properties box it changes to:
=Sum(IIf([accidYr]>2013,[numClaims],0))

The issue is that 2013 is now hard-coded and is no longer dynamic so it will lead to problems down the road.

Any suggestions?
Thank you.

Tried several variations with no luck.

Working:  =Sum(IIf([accidYr]>(Year()-6),[numClaims],0))

Changes to:  =Sum(IIf([accidYr]>2013,[numClaims],0))

No error messages, just an Access "feature" I presume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
=Sum(IIf([accidYr]>(Year(Date())-6),[numClaims],0))
```

Comment: That's easy: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).